# Cannot play streaming MP3 on windows media player

Tags: mp3, streaming, windows-media-player

This url (or any streaming mp3) cannot be played by my windows media player :

```
http://mp3.streampower.be/radio1-mid.mp3
```

It can be played however in for instance VLC.

The problem is that I want to listen to some streams on a website with in flash embedded windows media player, where the URL is not visible.  Since I cannot choose the player, I have no access to to the stream..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This url works pretty well on my windows media player.

It might be a codec problem.
VLC won't encounter these problems since it uses its own codecs (not those of WMP).

I suggest that you uninstall all codecs on your computer, then install [K-Lite Codec Pack](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/K_lite_codec_pack.htm).

If you want to verify which codecs are still installed, use [InstalledCodec](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/installed_codec.html).

Comment: I will try that

Comment: K-Lite Codec Pack is not even installed, but before installing, it worned me about some audioproblem on my PC and offered to fix it.  Now all works back.. tx man

Answer (score 1):

Well one problem is that WMP doesnt listen to .mp3 files for 'streams' open a direct mp3 file will only work on websites that the file is actually stored on, during mp3 streams there is no file saved it is a direct data stream not a file download.  I myself have been looking for some way to link a stream for automatic click listen for WMP but since most people stream in shoutcast that is winamp and .pls files which WMP cant not open (they use the m3u format)  WMP supports inside the program Open URL which then jsut the address:port# will then play properly but Im still trying to figure how to make a link myself even for it.